# Running Youtube embedded player inside (cocoa) screensaver - how to block/trap fake user events?

Tags: cocoa, webview, youtube, youtube-api, screensaver

The Youtube player seems to send fake user input events in order to prevent the screensaver from starting (I'm on osx/safari but the same thing happens in windows).  This happens both with the embedded players and the one on the yt site.  I'm guessing that this is by design so that the screensaver doesn't annoy you while you are trying to watch a video.

However, **I'm trying to play a youtube video from *within* a screensaver, so I would like to trap and ignore or turn off these events.**  My screensaver works great for 6-8 seconds when it exits gracefully just as if the user moved the mouse.  I think under windows I could catch it and ignore it, but I'm writing it for OSX, so I can't seem to trap it my code because it never reaches my code - it is handled by the ScreenSaverEngine app.  Mac screensavers are plugins to this app, so they can't override the main event loop (which calls NSApplication::sendEvent).  The first I hear about the event is in the applicationShouldTerminate() delegate.  I can request that the app terminate later, but this only postpones shutdown for about 1 second.  The stack trace is below - from what I can make out it is a MouseExit apple event being sent.

I've looked and looked, and I can't find a way to disable or catch these player events either in cocoa or in javascript.  My actual video is loaded into a WebView and runs using the youtube javascript api, but the below stripped down test code produces the same results.  I also get the same results without running any code by doing the following:

(1) Play a video in youtube (doesn't matter if embedded or not) 
(2) manually start your screensaver via hot corner or whatever 
(3) wait a few seconds

I assumed this was a bug in my code for a long time, because I'm new to objective-c and javascript but now I think it's by design because the above steps reproduce the problem without using my code at all.

Screensaver test code ----- .h file

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
#import <ScreenSaver/ScreenSaver.h>

@interface YtTestView : ScreenSaverView
{
    WebView * webView;
}

@end
```

Screensaver test code ----- .m file - I think most of the parameters are superfluous for this example, but this was adapted from an excellent example by Alastair Tse (https://github.com/liquidx/webviewscreensaver)

```
#import "YtTestView.h"

@implementation YtTestView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame isPreview:(BOOL)isPreview
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame isPreview:isPreview];
    if (self) {
        [self setAnimationTimeInterval:1/30.0];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)startAnimation
{
    [super startAnimation];

    webView = [[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:[self bounds]];
    [webView setFrameLoadDelegate:self];
    [webView setShouldUpdateWhileOffscreen:YES];
    [webView setPolicyDelegate:self];
    [webView setUIDelegate:self];
    [webView setEditingDelegate:self];
    [webView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];
    [webView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    [webView setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [webView setMaintainsBackForwardList:NO];
    [self addSubview:webView];

    NSString * url= @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/NleT--L6fNo?autoplay=1";
    [webView setMainFrameURL:url];
}

- (void)stopAnimation
{
    [super stopAnimation];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
}

- (void)animateOneFrame
{
    return;
}

- (BOOL)hasConfigureSheet
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSWindow*)configureSheet
{
    return nil;
}

@end
```

--------stack trace in applicationShouldTerminate() - just fyi

2013-05-20 23:41:20.558 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07]      Event: NSEvent: type=Kitdefined loc=(0,800) time=21467.6 flags=0 win=0x0 winNum=0 ctxt=0x0 subtype=1 data1=619 data2=0
2013-05-20 23:41:20.558 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] Window ClassName: (null)
2013-05-20 23:41:20.559 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] Event: type=13
2013-05-20 23:41:20.561 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 0: 0   Ytss                                0x0000000106167327 -[YtssView(NSApplicationDelegate) applicationShouldTerminate:] + 343
2013-05-20 23:41:20.562 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 1: 1   AppKit                              0x00007fff85623e6f -[NSApplication _docController:shouldTerminate:] + 75
2013-05-20 23:41:20.562 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 2: 2   AppKit                              0x00007fff85623d7e __91-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _closeAllDocumentsWithDelegate:shouldTerminateSelector:]_block_invoke_0 + 159
2013-05-20 23:41:20.562 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 3: 3   AppKit                              0x00007fff85623c1a -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _closeAllDocumentsWithDelegate:shouldTerminateSelector:] + 1557
2013-05-20 23:41:20.563 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 4: 4   AppKit                              0x00007fff856235de -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) __closeAllDocumentsWithDelegate:shouldTerminateSelector:] + 265
2013-05-20 23:41:20.563 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 5: 5   AppKit                              0x00007fff856234af -[NSApplication _shouldTerminate] + 772
2013-05-20 23:41:20.563 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 6: 6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8565127f -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEQuit] + 403
2013-05-20 23:41:20.566 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 7: 7   AppKit                              0x00007fff854001b1 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 660
2013-05-20 23:41:20.567 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 8: 8   Foundation                          0x00007fff8ea2370b -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 308
2013-05-20 23:41:20.567 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 9: 9   Foundation                          0x00007fff8ea2356d _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 106
2013-05-20 23:41:20.567 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 10: 10  AE                                  0x00007fff906fa078 _Z20aeDispatchAppleEventPK6AEDescPS_jPh + 307
2013-05-20 23:41:20.567 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 11: 11  AE                                  0x00007fff906f9ed9 *ZL25dispatchEventAndSendReplyPK6AEDescPS* + 37
2013-05-20 23:41:20.569 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 12: 12  AE                                  0x00007fff906f9d99 aeProcessAppleEvent + 318
2013-05-20 23:41:20.570 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 13: 13  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8d599709 AEProcessAppleEvent + 100
2013-05-20 23:41:20.570 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 14: 14  AppKit                              0x00007fff853fc866 _DPSNextEvent + 1456
2013-05-20 23:41:20.570 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 15: 15  AppKit                              0x00007fff853fbe22 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
2013-05-20 23:41:20.570 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 16: 16  ScreenSaverEngine                   0x0000000104b6e747 -[ScreenSaverApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 49
2013-05-20 23:41:20.571 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 17: 17  AppKit                              0x00007fff853f31d3 -[NSApplication run] + 517
2013-05-20 23:41:20.571 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 18: 18  ScreenSaverEngine                   0x0000000104b6e5a3 main + 551
2013-05-20 23:41:20.571 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 19: 19  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff907b47e1 start + 0
2013-05-20 23:41:20.571 ScreenSaverEngine[2143:c07] 20: 20  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1